# How to create form on users account page?

Tags: forms, users

I used `hook_user_view_aler()` to add some info to user's page.

```
 $account['summary']['member_five'] = array(
    '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
    '#title' => t('I do'),
    '#markup' => 'Real magic',
  );

  $account['summary']['member_six'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#size' => 30,
    '#maxlength' => 60,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $account['summary']['member_seven'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );
```

Also I added form elements and they do appear but I couldn't submit it. `hook_user_view_aler_submit()` obviously is too much and it doesn't work. Is there any way to create form on user's page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to define a form function using the drupal form API 
See this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/717722) for more info on how to make your own forms.

So the actual form function would look something like this

```
MY_FORM_FUNCTION($form, &$form_state){
  // Build form array here 
  return $form; 
}

MY_FORM_FUNCTION_validate($form, &$form_state){
  // Validate function here
}

MY_FORM_FUNCTION_submit($form, &$form_state){
  // Submit function here
}
```

Now in the tutorial they use `HOOK_menu` to display the form on a page. But you can call `drupal_get_form('MY_FORM_FUNCTION')` from everywhere and generate a render array for the form.

So this would show your form on the user page via HOOK_user_view_alter

```
 $account['form'] = drupal_get_form('MY_FORM_FUNCTION');
```